# How to use the native control of Stepper in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I use a Xamarin.Forms layout, and it has a `Stepper` control.

On Android, it looks like this:

[image]

Now it seems that I have to create custom cells on each platform as the UWP performance is way-way-way below the normal scrolling speed.

According to this page, the `Stepper` is rendered via a custom view in Android:

[image]

I created an Android layout, and I intend to use the StepperRenderer, but I don't know how to *inflate the custom view inside my custom viewcell*:

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/Layout1"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="10dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
        <!-- NumberPicker is not applicable-->
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/Stepper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!--StepperRenderer
        android:id="@+id/Stepper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /-->
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>


protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
{
  var x = (MyViewCell)item;

  var view = convertView;

  if (view == null)
  {
    // no view to re-use, create new
    view = (context as Activity).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyViewCellLayout, null);
  }

  view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text).Text = x.Text;
  view.FindViewById<NumberPicker>(Resource.Id.Stepper).Value = x.Value;

  return view;
}
```

Any idea how I could use that view in my viewCell?

Answer (score 0):

There is similar thread related to this:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26173/custom-renderer-for-stepper

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is useful if you want to create a custom Xamarin.Forms control, but I need to harness the power of the native performance so I need to have an Android control in my Android project. I don't want to reimplement it, I just want to reuse the StepperRenderer.